# Clicking token in NSTokenField

Tags: cocoa, nstokenfield

Is it possible to get an event when you click on a token in a NSTokenField?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seeing as those tokens (`NSTokenFieldCell`s) inherit from the `NSCell` class, in theory, yes, you can have them send an event by giving them an action and a target (`-setAction:` and `-setTarget:` respectively, and if you want to give the tokens menus when pressed, use `-setMenu:`).

Comment: How/where should I set the action which will be fired when clicking on a token field cell?

Comment: In your UI controller (whichever class you use to control actions associated with the user interface), you should declare a method that will get called when these tokens get pressed. By default, there's no way to access `NSTokenFieldCell`s from the `NSTokenField` to set the action and target, though, so you might have to do some subclassing to get it to work correctly.

Comment: I have created a MyNSTokenField to return MyNSTokenFieldCell (through <code>+ (Class)cellClass</code>, whereby I set MyNSTokenFieldCell's Target and Action though no event was sent.  Any idea what else I could do to get an event when clicked?

Comment: I'm wondering the same thing. Did you managed to get it solved?